# How to setup solidity inheritance?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Im trying to create a flow where contract A holds an address and all calls from contract B and contract C need to pass a simple msg.sender == systemAddress check.

All the while I need to be able to use any data in contract B within Contract C including the functions.

Here is a basic structure - not working, just trying to convey what I want to achieve.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {

    address systemAddress = 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266;

    constructor(){}

    function fromSystem(address from) public view {
        require(
            from == systemAddress,
            "Invalid transaction source"
        );
    }
}

contract B {

    A a;

    uint[] data;

    constructor(address contractA){
        a = A(contractA);
        data.push(10);
    }

    modifier fromSystem() {
        a.fromSystem(msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function funcB() public fromSystem returns (uint256){
        // do something
        return data[0];
    }
}

contract C {

    A a;
    B b;

    constructor(address contractA, address contractB){
        a = A(contractB);
        b = B(contractB);
    }

    modifier fromSystem() {
        a.fromSystem(msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function funcC() public fromSystem {
        uint num = b.funcB();
        // expecting 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity supports multiple inheritance. You can use Use `is` to derive from another contract. check out solidity docs for more information on [inheritance](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html?highlight=Inheritance#inheritance).
here how your example code will look like

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

contract A {

```
address systemAddress = 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2;

constructor(){
    
}

function funcA(address from) public view {
    require(
        from == systemAddress,
        "Invalid transaction source"
    );
}
```

}

contract B is A {

```
uint[] data;

constructor(){
   
    data.push(10);
}

modifier fromSystem() {
 require(
        msg.sender == systemAddress,
        "Only systemAddress can call this."
    );
    _;
}

function funcB() public view fromSystem returns (uint256){
    // do something
    return data[0];
}
```

}

contract C is A, B{

```
constructor(){
   
}

function funcC() view public fromSystem returns (uint256) {
    uint num = B.funcB();
    return num;
}
```

}